# How to print floats with for loop without other functions BUT range()

Tags: python-3.x

I want to Print all the numbers between 5 to 8, with jumps of 0.3.
I got 2 problems doing it:

1. It's not very accurate (I know the reason, what I dont know is how to get 5.89999999999 to become 5.9)
2. I dont know how to do it without any imports and functions (without numpy and without xrange which btw does not exist in python 3.x anymore as I understood)

This is just for a Homework question, I'm a new python learner, so I dont realy know ALL the tools and tricks of python.

```
max = 9
min = 5
step = 0.3
while min <= max:
    min += step
    print(min)

Expected:
5, 
5.3,
5.6,
5.9,
6.2,
...

Actual reasults:
5.3,
5.6,
5.89999999995,
6.1999999999,
6.4999999999,
...
```

Comment: Read up on string formatting: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: You shouldn't use `max` or `min` as variable names as they are keywords in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just round `min` using `round()` before printing it. If you want the original value of the variable to be also printed, you'll want to change the position of the print statement.

```
while min <= max:
    print(min)
    min+=step
    # rounds min to the first decimal place
    min = round(min,1)
```

Results:

```
5
5.3
5.6
5.9
6.2
6.5
6.8
7.1
7.4
7.7
8.0
8.3
8.6
8.9
9.2
```